# Can we use CSS in Android forms for android components?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

is there anyway to use css for android controls, and can we make classes for similar controls.

Thanks
Atif

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why do you want to define CSS for the Android views? First let me know the answer of this question, otherwise i would like to tell you that you can defines the same kind of styles inside the [styles.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) file and then can implement for any views inside the xml layout file.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

At initial level, you face some difficulty but later on as you became aware about defining xml layout file, you will be used to define styles for different views easily.

### Update:

As per your comment below, i can say you are not knowing much more about styles and theme in android, so i would like to suggest you below links to know about styles/theme to apply in android.

1. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html
2. http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-themes-and-styles-in-android.html

Comment: I have no problem in using its styles, but css is a proper way, like if i have 70 fields, i would give it a class name, and all fields will follow one pattern, but in it what i know yet is you have to give style yourself to each field.

Comment: Its same to give style name as class name.

Comment: I dont find any styles folder or styles file, can you tell me location.

Comment: in "values" folder in your application, just define "styles.xml" file.

Comment: @PareshMayani Dear friend, okay you're used to and have got used to make the style of your app through style.xml, but who has experience in using css know how this technique is practical. Only by css indeed have features such as inheritance and overridden, would be enough to be adopted in the development android. Can create generic classes of styles, extend these to their necessides, change them at times and all this with little code now would be a great saving of time in developing for android. think about it and open your mind to the already established technical development.

Comment: @WalterGandarella I know about CSS as I was PHP developer prior coming into the android world :-)

Comment: I am php developer too! that small world!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can try [Nativecss](http://nativecss.com). It's a libary that you can use css-like selectors in android layout.

--------- Updated on May 10th, 2015 -----------

Or a completely new way to write app, [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/)

Answer (score 1):

you can define [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html), but if you want to use CSS you need a HTML form which you can show in a Native Android WebView (an idea on which phonegap platform runs)