# CSS in TextView Android

Tags: android, html, css, textview

I have a *html* string that I want to display in *TextView*. The *html* string has *css* inline style and also *css* in header. I would like to ask if I can display the *html* string with *css* in *TextView*?

I tried `Html.fromHtml()`, but the *css* doesn't apply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we use CSS in Android forms for android components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843842/can-we-use-css-in-android-forms-for-android-components)

Answer (score 3):

Android native TextView doesn't support all HTML tags and features. It only does support a [few tags and properties](https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html). So, in your case, there's a couple of options which you may want to consider.

Use `WebView` to show rich texts. However, `WebViews` are too heavy and slow.

Use 3rd party libraries that improve native `TextView` and support more HTML tags. For example: [HTML-TextView](https://github.com/PrivacyApps/html-textview).

Comment: Sorry, but Android native TextView doesn't support all HTML tags and features

Answer (score 0):

Android does not support CSS in *TextView* and has a [limited Html markup support](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithHTML). Use [WebView](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview) instead.