# Show style and ul li tag in android Textview

Tags: android, html, css

I have String with ul,li and style tag in it. And I am trying to show them in HTML formatting in textview.

**String**

```
    <style type='text/css'> 
ul
{
     list-style-type: circle;
     font-size: 16px;
}
```

```
<div style='font-family: Montserrat;line-height: 30px; text-align: left; color: #383838;'> 
<ul>
     <li>
        Hello Everyone <span style='font-weight: 600; color: #b49fe1;'>Good Morning</span> How are You ?.</br>
    </li> 
    <li>
        Good morning <span style='color: #b49fe1;font-weight: 600;'>Have a nice day</span>.</br>
    </li> 
 </ul>
```

textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myHtmlText));

But textview shows the plain text.

SomeHow i managed to convert the ul and li tag by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36942941/10279394) but didn't look like i want .

Is anyone know How can I have use style,ul and li tag in textview?

Comment: use `webview` instead

Comment: Thankyou @Sultan Mahmud But i found a library that works fine for me [MarkDown Library](https://github.com/tiagohm/MarkdownView)

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit webview not converting the Font tags that's why i use Markdown View Library.

Comment: [Android does not support CSS in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53180039/3290339)

Answer (score 0):

You are using CSS but CSS is not supported in android. You can use webview instead.

Below tags are supported in android.For more details look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29)

```
br
p
div
em
b
strong
cite
dfn
i
big
small
font
blockquote
tt
monospace
a
u
sup
sub
```