# Android Html.fromHtml(span) is not working for mark tag

Tags: android, html

- Method

  ```
  public Spanned fromHtml(String html) {
     Spanned result;
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
         result = Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
     } else {
         // This method is deprecated but need to use for old os devices
         return Html.fromHtml(html);
     }
     return result;
  }
  ```

input

```
String description = "Normal text <mark style=\"font-weight:600;color:#000;\">highlight this text</mark> not working";
```

It is showing normal text on `TextView`.

It seems [Html.Java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java#791) doesn't contain **mark** tag. Is there any workaround for this?

Please don't suggest spannable string with start index and end index because string lengh is dynamic one.

Comment: [CSS in TextView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53180039/3290339)

Comment: @Onik in library readme file mark tag is not covered in supported text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any workaround for this?

Option #1: Change the text to use a supported tag at its source, to avoid the use of `<mark>`

Option #2: Create your own parser that can handle this tag, identifying the start and end positions, and creating a `Spanned` using `SpannableStringBuilder`, [the way that `Html` does](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java)

Option #3: Use a regex to try to replace the `<mark>` and `</mark>` with some supported tag, then parse that modified string with `Html`

Option #4: Use `WebView` to render this markup

Option #5: Use a regex to try to eliminate the `<mark>` and `</mark>` tags, so you can just use the plain string

Comment: parser is the way to go but I will look for alternatives. I will accept this if I don't get any proper solution.