# Set TextView within RemoteViews to CSS-styled html text

Tags: android, html, textview, remoteview

I'm using the following code to set the text within a `TextView` (itself within a `RemoteViews`), where `htmlText` below is text wrapped in html markup, including css styles to set the text colour and weight:

```
Spanned styledText = Html.fromHtml(htmlText, FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text_view, styledText);
```

The text is at least being interpreted as html text (i.e. I see the text, not the markup) but styling such as `style="font-size:52.03px;font-weight:bolder;color:rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);"` is being ignore... I'm particular wanting the text *colour* to be honoured... not so bothered about the weight and size.

How do I get the css styling within the html markup to be honoured?

Comment: You can set the textColor from xml. Why do you want to set it dynamically?

Comment: According to [CSS in TextView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53180039/css-in-textview-android), using css will not work.

Comment: For text colour you can use it as remoteView.setTextColor(Color). Also textviews don't support all CSS properties. Here is the link to already answered question for css and textview https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53180039/css-in-textview-android

Comment: You can try to generate a SpannableString from your html, see [https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568)

Comment: @0X0nosugar kindof... that answer suggests that TextView doesn't support all html tags, which is true, but the following suggests that CSS color style *is* supported: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StylingWithHTML

Comment: OK, then I think (no, sorry: I guess and can't make sure right now) it's the mixture of supported (color) and non supported (font, font-weight) together in one css-attribute. Can you try and just set the color?

Comment: OK I think colour works, but not specified by `color:rgba(...)` and only by colour name e.g. `color:red`.  This is a shame as I'm getting the html markup (with styles) from another source and it would be a PITA to have to convert.